# Why is py.test ignoring random seeding on os x?

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scikit-learn, pytest

I've been experiencing some odd issues with randomness in `scikit-learn` on my macbook. (OS X 10.12.6, `conda` environment with `python 2.7`). As a test, I've set up the following script:

```
import numpy.random as npr
import numpy.testing as npt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer


def test_randomness_one():
    npr.seed(54)
    rand_ints_one = npr.randint(500, size=50)
    npr.seed(54)
    rand_ints_two = npr.randint(500, size=50)
    npt.assert_array_equal(rand_ints_one, rand_ints_two)


def test_logit_one():
    data = load_breast_cancer()
    preds_one = LogisticRegression(random_state=2)\
                .fit(data['data'], data['target'])\
                .decision_function(data['data'])
    preds_two = LogisticRegression(random_state=2)\
                .fit(data['data'], data['target'])\
                .decision_function(data['data'])
    npt.assert_array_equal(preds_one, preds_two)


def test_logit_two():
    data = load_breast_cancer()
    preds_one = LogisticRegression()\
                .fit(data['data'], data['target'])\
                .decision_function(data['data'])
    preds_two = LogisticRegression()\
                .fit(data['data'], data['target'])\
                .decision_function(data['data'])
    npt.assert_array_equal(preds_one, preds_two)

# A note: main used for testing with the interpreter directly
# Executed with pytest *without* the below lines.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_randomness_one()
    test_logit_one()
    test_logit_two()
```

In theory, all of these results should be identical, and coworkers running Ubuntu and windows boxes have verified this. On my box, all of these tests pass if executed in a REPL or run via `python toy_test.py`. If run via `pytest toy_test.py`, however, `test_logit_one` fails consistently and `test_logit_two` fails often but not always. Where is the randomness coming from in this situation? Is it OS-level? `conda`-level? `pytest`? Or something else?

Comment: I don't know much about pytest, but are you sure this kind of main-function is the way to go? I always thought looking for tests is just about class and function-names (suffix) and in this case it's also unclear to me in what order those are executed (as seen or lexicographically). Maybe you will want to try [this approach](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/667) (or just seed in each function; ugly, i know).

Comment: @sascha the `if __name__ == "__main__"` will be there so it can be run with `python toy_test.py`, instead of `pytest toy_test.py`, as that apparently makes a difference.

Comment: The [LogisticRegression documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) has a clear note on this: "The underlying C implementation uses a random number generator to select features when fitting the model. It is thus not uncommon, to have slightly different results for the same input data.". So for every case the test did *not* fail, I'd say that was just luck (and some underlying machine caching). Looks like Pytest on OS X just messes up the initial conditions for the rng  enough to let the tests fail.

Comment: And given Evert's last comment i'm not sure if ```assert_array_equal``` is the way to go. Consider: ```assert_allclose```.

Comment: `npt.assert_allclose` doesn't change performance here, I'm afraid.

Comment: What do you mean? It's a convex opt-problem and the solver needs to obtain convergence (in practice this might look different; especially for ill-conditioned data or very bad regularization parameters). If then decreasing tol as said in sklearn's docs, numerically indistinguishable solutions should be obtained regardless of the external PRNG. But even if those are numerically indistinguishable, array_equal might fail (is expected to), while allclose should not.

Comment: hmm, ok. In practice, even with `tol=0.0000000000000000001` I still don't get `npt.assert_allclose` to pass with the default `decimal=7`. So the amount of variance is high. I think I'm mostly unsettled because I'm the only one for whom pytest misbehaves in this manner.

Comment: That does not make much sense to me (but i won't argue about it). Maybe show your changes and where does decimal=7 come from?

Comment: Have you compared the actual difference between the arrays? For example, by simply printing it to stdout (or, for large arrays, the sum, median or a few elements). I'd be curious how big the difference really is.